# Google Place Autocomplete destroying the parent fragment it is in

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have a Google places autocomplete fragment implemented as follows

```
    AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment) 
      getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
    LatLng center = ((LocationActivity)getActivity()).getLastLocationLatLng();
    if (center != null){
        LatLng northSide = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, 50000, 0);//50,000 meters
        LatLng southSide = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, 50000, 180);

        LatLngBounds bounds = LatLngBounds.builder()
                .include(northSide)
                .include(southSide)
                .build();

        autocompleteFragment.setLocationBias(RectangularBounds.newInstance(bounds));
    }

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            Log.i(GlobalVar.TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            selectedLatLng = place.getLatLng();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {

            Log.i(GlobalVar.TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

This widget is in one of the fragments in the BottomNavigationView.

So BottomNavigiationView -> Third tab -> you will see the Google places search

When I click on search, type, and choose one of the results then the app goes back to the first Tab!.

I do get `Log.i(GlobalVar.TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());` executed which means the autocomplete retrieved the resuts but for some reason the parent fragment (Third tab) is destroyed/deattached

What do you suggest?

Thank you

Comment: You may need a billing account.

Comment: I have it. And like I said, I am getting results successfully

Comment: Did you use Places.initialize?

Comment: Yes I have it in the beginning of the gragment. IT could be a bottomnavigationview actiivtiy issue too

Comment: Please can you provide the full code and layout so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?